# UNIX Comparing string with space from command output

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a delimited flat file and I want to find the column position of a user given header. The problem is some of my headers have spaces in them, and when I do a comparison it treats the string of two words as two arguments. My code will work if none of the delimited fields have spaces in them.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Unique Values
#Example use: my_script file.txt '|' 'SOME VARIABLE'

DELIM=$2
VAR=$3
HEADERS=$(sed -n 1p $1)
COUNTER=1

while [ $VAR != $(echo $HEADERS | cut -d $DELIM -f $COUNTER) ]
do
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
done
echo $COUNTER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the variables in quotes

```
while [ "$VAR" != "$(echo $HEADERS | cut -d $DELIM -f $COUNTER)" ]
```

or use [[ instead of [

```
while [[ $VAR != $(echo $HEADERS | cut -d $DELIM -f $COUNTER) ]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Could you please explain why [[ worked instead of [?

Comment: That is how [[ works. It prevents word splitting of variable values and also wildcard expansion of pathnames.

Comment: However, you should be aware that [[ is available in more modern shells and may not work on all shells (e.g. Bourne Shell)

Comment: I always use first method but saw people using [[ too. Never knew why. Thanks for sharing. My upvote for you :)